# What is the time complexity of the RC6 encryption?

Tags: rc6

I am confused to analyze time complexity of rc6 encryption. Please help me

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried, and got stuck on?

Comment: I want to measure the complexity of rc6. Seen from the time table shows O (1) because the time average is same..but i am confused to specify big oh any rc6 algorithm function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of encryption, decryption and brute forcing a block cipher key are all O(1). This is a fixed problem with no apparent n. If you want to encrypt many blocks using some sane mode (cbc,cfb,ctr,...) the complexity would obviously be O(n).
Cryptographers often misuse assymptotic complexity annotations and write stuff like O(2^128) which is silly as it is still O(1).